# Extending protocol from a class with categories in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, protocols, categories

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
id<MyDelegate> _delegate;
....
[_delegate performSelectorOnMainThread...]

@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
....
```

My problem is that performSelectorOnMainThread is defined in a category of NSObject so the compiler doesn't recognize it. I get:
"warning: '-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:' not found in protocol(s)"
I could cast the delegate but that defeats the purpose of the delegate. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd need to see more code to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your delegate as `NSObject<MyDelegate> * _delegate;`.

This tells the compiler that `_delegate` *must* be an instance of `NSObject` or subclass that *must* respond to the requirements of the `MyDelegate` protocol.